# How to assign a text-variable to a textfield in Visio 2013?

Tags: visio

I want to model something in Visio but when I change a word that I'm using often, I don't want to change it manually at all its occurrences.

Example:
[image: 2"Hi"-Textfields]
My goal: When I change "hi" (inside any of those text fields) to something else like "test" the other text field(s) should also change their text to "test".

Is there an easy way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use fields
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-text-field-into-a-shape-0225c22e-3e5e-4ea7-9ca0-1ec91386cb1e

as Custom formula use this syntax
*Shapetext(Sheet.ID!TheText)*
where ID - is ID-number of reference shape

Comment: ah, I think you got me on the right track but there's no `ID` in your syntax `Shapetext(Sheet.!TheText)` - I don't quite understand

Comment: I got it, in the Developer-tools tab I found out the name (Shape13) of one of the shapes and inserted a field in the other shape with `Shapetext(Shape13!TheText)`

Comment: i prefer use shape ID instead shape name! somebode can change name, but Shape ID is constant !

Comment: Visio have local and universal names for shapes and pages !!! look my old post - http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=5351.msg30121#msg30121

Answer (score 0):

look this gif with my explain !
http://s019.radikal.ru/i621/1705/c4/ccaa00a0bf67.gif